# UILocalNotification in background - iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, cllocationmanager, uilocalnotification

I have a navigation app that uses `UILocalNotification` when getting location updates.

When the app goes to the background on iOS 9 devices (lock screen / pressed home button) - it stops getting the notifications. Works on iOS 8 devices.

I'm getting the notifications when the app is in the foreground, but not in background (which is, of course, far more important).

Code looks something like this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations
{
    CLLocation *currLocation = [locations lastObject];

    CLLocationDistance dist = [currLocation distanceFromLocation:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.coordinate.latitude longitude:self.coordinate.longitude]];

    BOOL gotToDestination = dist < 60;

    if (gotToDestination) {
        UILocalNotification* n1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        n1.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have arrived!"];
        n1.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        n1.fireDate = [NSDate date];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:n1];
    }
}
```

- I have requested always authorization
- I have checked Background modes -> Location updates
- I have registered for user notifications

Will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i've got it.

The problem wasn't with the `UILocalNotification`, but with the location manager.

As of iOS 9, `CLLocationManager` has a new BOOL property - `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` which defaults to NO.

If you want to keep getting location updates, you probably want to set it to YES.

This solved my problem.

Comment: Please note that your app may be suspended or killed after 30 seconds being in background. To prevent it, you should ask iOS explicitly to allow background exection: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html . Funny, but iOS simulator does not kill your app, while real device does.

Comment: Thanks, i was aware of that but it's good for future readers :)